# Tomcat 8 DeltaManager vs BackupManager session replication

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, replication, tomcat8

I'm going to configure 2 nodes cluster with a separated AWS EC2 instances with Tomcat 8 installed.

I need to configure Tomcat session replication.

According to Tomcat 8 documentation [Clustering/Session Replication HOW-TO](http://talenthuntonline.com/docs/cluster-howto.html):

> In this release of session replication, Tomcat can perform an all-to-all replication of session state using the DeltaManager or perform backup replication to only one node using the BackupManager. The all-to-all replication is an algorithm that is only efficient when the clusters are small. For larger clusters, to use a primary-secondary session replication where the session will only be stored at one backup server simply setup the BackupManager.

Could you please tell me what does it mean - **clusters are small** ?

Is it 2.. 5..100... 1000 nodes or what ?

Comment: Use quote formatting for text that is quoted, and don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tomcat clustering/session replication method in your question uses multicast. Since I see you also have this question tagged with `amazon-ec2` you need to know that you can't use multicast on AWS, or any other cloud service for that matter.

To implement Tomcat session replication on AWS I would recommend looking into methods that use [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-dynamodb-session-manager-for-apache-tomcat/), [Redis](https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager), or [RDS](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook-2nd/059652708X/ch20s05.html).

Comment: The delta manager uses multicast. The backup manager does not.

Comment: @EJP +1 Plus, BackupManager scales much better than the `DeltaManager`, anyway. For my money, `DeltaManager` is a good way to get things proven-out and configured in a dev/test environment, while `BackupManager` is much more appropriate for production.

Comment: The link to RDS implementation seems to be broken.